# Jquery UI Shake Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use the jquery shake effect to draw attention to a particular link.

The link is `<a href="http://example.com" class="noticeMe">Link</a>`

The example script I found for the shake effect is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function() {
$('.noticeMe').effect('shake',{ times:4, distance:10}, 1000);
}, 5000);
});
```

And I have the following Jquery versions linked:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>`

The shake effect does not work though and I cannot seem to understand why since I have the newest jquery libraries linked, and copy/pasted the example code.

Am I missing something?

The jsfiddle for the example is http://jsfiddle.net/ipyxel/YRGb5/ (This fiddle is not my code but the example from the tutorial).

From what I can tell I have everything setup properly, but to no avail.

I'm on my tablet(android) so unfortunatly I cannot view the console to know if anything is happening there.

Forgot to mention but the tutorial is at http://ipyxel.com/3-simple-yet-effective-jquery-techniques-youll-use-time-and-again/

Comment: the text is shaking what are you expecting anyway?

Comment: Is the text not shaking on your android device?

Comment: The fiddle is an example and not my code, but on my live site it does not shake even though i used the same code.

Comment: It looks like .effect comes from jQuery UI and you aren't including that in the script tags in your question.

Comment: Yeah turns out when i was viewing the source and such i overlooked that being a seperate library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have problem in the connecting of library, i use `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>` and `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js">` and working correctly, try to look here. http://jsbin.com/puhelaperi/edit?html,js,console,output